# Pass an Array to JavaScript Callback

Tags: javascript, oop, debugging, syntax

I'm pretty familiar with jQuery, but as most of you know, there's a big difference between jQuery and vanilla javascript.  I'm trying to get deeper into vanilla javascript and I have some code and some questions.

In the code below I'm trying to take HTML generated via the export feature from Writeboard.com (which is retired http://37signals.com/writeboard-retired).  Basically, I'm trying to get some useful practice and write a script that will find specific content e.g. `<li>//Title:...</li>` and push that into a JSON array which I will then parse as XML.  The final goal is to get all of this as XML so that it's more portable (both away from the legacy Writeboard.com boards and also for direct import into the web app I'm working on).

So, I have a ways to go and I'm not looking for anyone to write the code for me, but I'm trying to wrap my mind around a few things:

- Trying to create a callback called `TargetList` which allows the user to pass an array as follows to tell the script special "keys" (values) which will then be searched for. The parent `<li>` will have it's content extracted and saved to the JSON array so that the `<li>` containing element can be abandoned and the XML attribute (e.g. `<title>`) can wrap it instead.
- My understanding of the proper syntax for setting up an array in JS would be `var targetList = [];` to create an empty array which I can then fill later as I loop through the search, find, and save aspects of the script.  I think I've set this up wrong and I'm not sure why.

  - I'm also confused why I can't just call the `convertToXML(['//Title:','//Prerequisite:','//Description:']);` function later in the script, I was getting errors on that and not sure why.  The error I was getting resulted in my assumption that I was improperly setting a target so I just creating one by wrapping the function in `document.ready` which I realize is unnecessary when calling out to the earlier function later in the script, though I'm not sure why I was having difficulty.

I realize that some of this has to do with OOP principles which I'm still learning, be gentle with me, I'm hoping that someone can explain to me why I'm going wrong.  I'd be super grateful!

```
( function ($) { // wrap jQuery to prevent conflicts

    $(document).ready(function () {

        function convertToXML (targetList) {

            var targetList = [];

            var i = 0; 
            while (i<=targetList.length) {
                var target = targetList[i];
                targetList.push( target );              
                i++;
            };
        };

        $(document).ready(function() {
            convertToXML(['Title:','Prerequisite:','Cost:','Description:','Effect:','Categories:' ]);
        });     


    }); // end document.ready

} ) ( jQuery );
```

Comment: Are you confusing targetList with some other variable name? Maybe capital T as in TargetList? In your convertToXML function, you have targetList as an argument, which you overwrite to an empty array. Then you loop over it and try to push each item to the same array. I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you think you'd need callbacks for that?

Comment: I'm using callbacks because I want to make the portable and non-repetitive, I have a number of documents (each with their own `<ul>`'s with different bullet-items).  My intent is to just include the script as a plugin that can be called in a document head and simply passed the variables as an array in the callback and then search for those, grab the `<li>` content and parse the markup to XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can answer your second question, but you will need to elaborate more on your first question.

The reason you can't call `convertToXML` later in the page is that you have wrapped it in a scope. (In fact, it's in two.)

```
function($) {
    // creates an anonymous function which takes one parameter (named $)
}

(function($) {
    // creates an anonymous function which takes one parameter,
    // and immediately calls it, passing the variable named jQuery to the parameter named $
})(jQuery);
```

This is a common pattern using jQuery to overcome the problem that other libraries sometimes take over the special $ variable name.  But what it's important to understand is anything you define inside that anonymous method cannot be accessed from outside the method.  So, if you want to access your `convertToXML` method from outside, you need to move the definition of it outside that block.

In addition:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // create an anonymous function, and pass it to jQuery's document.ready method,
    // jQuery will call your function when the DOM is loaded.
});
```

You've done this twice... and I'm pretty sure the second one won't get called since it's inside the first, which gets called when the DOM is loaded, and the DOM is only loaded once.  Remove one of these.

Comment: Thanks! That makes alot of sense, I realize that I've run into this before, still getting it committed to memory.  To elaborate on question 1: 


I'm using callbacks because I want to make the portable and non-repetitive, I have a number of documents (each with their own <ul>'s with different bullet-items). My intent is to just include the script as a plugin that can be called in a document head and simply passed the variables as an array in the callback and then search for those, grab the <li> content and parse the markup to XML.  Does that clarify the intent?

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is "method" or "function".  "Callback" is usually used to mean a function that is called when some other function finishes or some event happens.  For example, the anonymous function you pass to ```$(document).ready()``` is a callback, it gets called back when the document is ready.

Comment: Got it.  For the record, however, more testing proved that wrapping the function in jQuery is not the issue.  I'm still working to figure it out, but both the `$(document).ready(function() {
            convertToXML(['Title:','Prerequisite:','Cost:','Description:','Effect:','Categories:' ]);
        }); ` and the similar `convertToXML([ ... ]);` both cause the error the script is reporting.  Don't want to drag this out forever, but to future viewers of this question, beware, the code sited as erroneous is only *partially* erroneous `(function($) { }) (jQuery);` is just fine.